# How does the date has been overdue based on sysdate which got overdue in present week

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to meet the below requirement

```
•   Overdue 
o   This Week (Count)
o   Past 3 Weeks (Count)
o   Beyond 3 Weeks (Count)
•   Due
o   This Week (Count)
o   Within 3 Weeks (Count)
o   Beyond 3 Weeks (Count)
```

I have tried the below query

```
select to_date('05-MAY-17') > sysdate-6 and
to_date('05-MAY-17') < sysdate-6 then 'Y'
else 'N' from dual;
```

Here i have hard coded the week.. I am not sure this is right? Please suggest me the better way to satisfy my requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `to_date` function call is wrong, should be `to_date('05-MAY-17','DD-MONTH-YY')'.  You need to tell the to_date function the format the date string in in.

Comment: Give some sample data and expected output. Your requirement is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you are supposed to be querying a table in something like a library application. So what you need is something like this stack of conditional counts:

```
select 
   count( case when due_date < sysdate
                and due_date > sysdate-7 then 1 end ) overdue_one_week
   , count( case when due_date <= sysdate-7 
                  and due_date > sysdate-21 then 1 end ) overdue_three_week
   , count( case when due_date <= sysdate-21 then 1 end ) overdue_longer
   , count( case when due_date >= sysdate 
                  and due_date < sysdate+7 then 1 end ) due_this_week
   , count( case when due_date >= sysdate+7 
                  and due_date < sysdate+21 then 1 end ) due_three_weeks
   , count( case when due_date >= sysdate+21 then 1 end ) due_beyond_three_weeks
from library_loans
/
```